# Javascript, Window context

Tags: javascript

I try to understand how does the window object wrap my code i will explain, For example i got this theory:

```
function window(){
  // The window.window is in circular structure because window property on 
  // the window object  is set to this (this.window = this)


 // All the rest of the developer code goes here
}

window.call({});
```

This is probably a bad theory, But i wanted to try, **My question** is how the window object wrap my code how does it looks like, **And** if i am right about the window.window circular structure?

**Edit:**

What i want to understand is how is the window object is available to me as my global scope, How does it wrap my code, Is it same or similar to my example?, How the window object is structured behind the scene?

**Edit:**

Thank you for the answer c-smile, Please just tell me if i got you right,

The internalEval function is a javascript engine function written in java or c++ and so on...?

Also when you say script block you mean all the code between `<script></script>`?

When you say "and external script file loaded into the view" you mean that any other `<script></script>` tags content founded in the html page will be evaluated against the window scope(global scope)?

And about the window object: The first line that the browser execute before any script is `var window = {};` that will represent my global scope, The next step is to build the empty window object by assigning the `window.__proto__ = Window;`, Now i belive that the Window (function Window() { [native code] }) is assigned to the global(window) object before this line: `window.__proto__ = Window;` for example:

```
var window = {};
window.Window = function Window() { [native code] }
window.__proto__ = Window;
```

I really think i got it but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why? Please tell us what you are trying to do

Comment: Would you elaborate a bit on what you meant by "how does the window object wrap my code?"

window is a global object that DOM exposes so we can access properties of current page user is on.

In terms of why window.window exists, you may find this useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.window

Comment: @mplungjan It makes me curious.

Comment: @DashK Thank you for the link, I did edit my answer to explain a bit more about what make me curious, And is the window property is set like this.window = this; inside the window object?

Comment: You can’t express in JavaScript itself how it works. `window` is just the global object/scope for in-browser execution.

Comment: @poke There must be an answer, I know that there may be different implementations in different browser i just want to know if there is an answer that can be explained...

Comment: Yes, but browsers usually aren’t written in JavaScript, so you can’t really explain it with JavaScript code. The global object is [part of the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1), and `window` just happens to take that job for browsers.

Comment: @poke Thank you for the link, Can you please just explain the first to lines from the link:                                           "The unique global object is created before control enters any execution context."
And
"Unless otherwise specified, the standard built-in properties of the global object have attributes {[[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true}."

Comment: You can explain it in an answer to this question so i can approve your answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have some script block on your web page:

```
<script>
  var loc = window.location;  
  ... 
</script>
```

Here is what browser is doing when it needs to run the script in that block:

1. Create window namespace object:

   `var window = {}; window.window = window;`
2. Set it prototype to the Window "class"

   `window.__proto__ = Window;`
3. Eval the code in context of the window as global namespace object:

   `internalEval("content of that script block", window);`
4. Do #3 for each script block and external script file loaded into the view.

So if your script has statement like this:

```
someGlobalVar = 1234;
```

that someGlobalVar will be created as a property of window object:

```
window.someGlobalVar; // -> 1234 value here
```

And you cannot create global function with the name `window` as that variable 
is already defined and configured as read only. So that `window.window = window;` statement above actually looks like:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "window", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: window
});
```

Comment: Hey c-smile, Thank you for your answer, I edited my question can you please check i understand you explanation correct.

Comment: Steps 1..4 are done in native code behind the scene, I put them just to illustrate what conceptually is going on there. 
"content of that script block" is a source of script, anything between <script>...</script> tags or, if it is an external resource, content of that external resource as it is.

Comment: This `window.__proto__ = Window;` just transforms that `window` into an instance of Window class. So when you call `window.open("new url")` it actually calls method 'open' found in Window ( in its `Window.prototype` object )

Comment: So there is no steps (1,2,3,4) they all happen at the native code behind the scene, The only code happen at the js is the Object.defineProperty?

Comment: No, *nothing* happens in JavaScript. As I explained multiple times, you cannot express this in JS. The JS runtime does all this.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1), there needs to be some global object that fulfills certain roles. It provides [the global environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.2.3), the outmost scope. The global object is something that is created by the JavaScript engine itself, before any JavaScript code actually runs; and you cannot really express how that works in JavaScript code itself.

For browsers executing in the context with a DOM, `window` happens to be that global object. Every JavaScript runtime will have one; but what it is depends on where it’s running. For example in Node, the [`global`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) object (what a great name, huh?) takes that role.

Answer (score 1):

"window" is created prior to any execution context and cannot be used as the names of a variable or routine in global scope.  Here's a great reference @poke linked to: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1

The window object is used to retrieve information about the window and every frame on a page will have a window object.

Here's some more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873(v=vs.85).aspx

Note: There are some inconsistencies in the MSDN article and the EMCAScript.  @Poke pointed out in comments.

Comment: `window` is not a reserved keyword. You can redefine it just fine: `(function () { var window = 'foo'; console.log(window); })()` prints foo…

Comment: Well that is within the scope.  At the global level it is. var window = 'foo'; console.log(window)

Comment: That doesn’t make it a [reserved keyword](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word).

Comment: @poke Fair enough.  To be more specific, the window's properties, methods, and collection names are reserved keywords and cannot be used as the names of variables or routines.  I feel like we are debating a somewhat moot point and I was over generalizing.

Comment: To also add reference: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm

Comment: Most of those are not reserved words but simply predefined objects. Really the only accepted reference for reserved words in JavaScript is [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1)… And no, window’s properties are not reserved words either. They just happen to be non-writeable properties of the global object which is why you can’t overwrite them at global scope.

Comment: @poke great reference. Thanks for this.  Link to the global you mentioned http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1

Comment: I mention that in my answer too btw.